# How to fight "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have native [module](https://github.com/skycocker/react-native-sfsafariviewcontroller)  for React Native, that opens Safari View Controller:

RCTSFSafariViewController.m:

```
#import "RCTSFSafariViewController.h"

@implementation RCTSFSafariViewController

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"SFSafariViewControllerDismissed" body:nil];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openURL:(NSString *)urlString params:(NSDictionary *)params) {
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

  SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:safariViewController];

  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  safariViewController.delegate = self;

  if ([params objectForKey:@"tintColor"]) {
    UIColor *tintColor = [RCTConvert UIColor:params[@"tintColor"]];

    if([safariViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredControlTintColor:)]) {
      safariViewController.preferredControlTintColor = tintColor;
    } else {
      safariViewController.view.tintColor = tintColor;
    }
  }

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [rootViewController.rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
      [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"SFSafariViewControllerDidLoad" body:nil];
    }];
  });
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(close) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
    [rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  });
}

@end
```

RCTSFSafariViewController.h:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@import SafariServices;

@interface RCTSFSafariViewController : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

It works well in simulator and my iPhone, but a lot of users are facing such crash (according to Crashlytics):

```
Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x14e3bd20> was mutated while being enumerated.' was thrown while invoking openURL on target SFSafariViewController with params ( "https://example.com", { } )
```

The problem is that there is no arrays or enumerating constructions in this code. I have this idea that this could be caused by dispatch_async, because when I remove it, app stop crashing, but works incredebly slow after calling SVC.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is being called on a non-main queue. If it were on the main queue, then your `dispatch_sync` should deadlock. It is not safe to interact with most UIKit objects off the main queue. That likely includes `SFSafariViewController` (unless you have explicit documentation saying it is safe, then it isn't).

Calling `dispatch_sync` is generally dangerous (without care it can lead to deadlocks), and in this case unnecessary. You could definitely use `dispatch_async` here.

You should move this entire method into a `dispatch_async` call to the main queue.

Comment: I use dispatch_async and dispatch_sync was my desperate experiment. But last paragraph seems to be possible solution. I'll try it. Anyways, big thanks for answer.

Comment: Somehow, wrapping the entire method into `dispatch_async` causes deadlock when calling SFSafariViewController :(

Comment: Wrapping the whole method and removing the `dispatch_sync`, or leaving the `dispatch_sync`? If you don't remove the `dispatch_sync` call, this would absolutely deadlock (that would be the canonical example of a deadlock).

Comment: Wrapping the whole method and removing the `dispatch_sync` is my case. But actually I solved the problem with deadlocks, it was caused by React Native Navigation module.